# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exog' in statsmodel logit model

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, statsmodels

I have a dataframe like so:

```
CRP    WEI   Kfact   CPI
0      1.2   4.5     2.3
0      0.5   5.0     0.2
0      1.1   1.4     3.2
1      3.8   6.7     9.2
1      2.3   5.6     9.5
1      1.3   3.4     8.3
```

and I want to run a logit model using statsmodel using `CRP` as the endogenous variable (dependent). I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df=pd.read_csv(C:\path)

feature_cols=[col for col in df.columns if ('CRP' not in col)]
X=df[feature_cols].values
y=df['CRP'].values

X=sm.add_constant(X.exog, prepend=False)
y=y.endog

log_res = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()

print log_res.summary()
```

but this returns:

```
File "H:/Stefano/python codes/location_assessment/logit_model.py", line 23, in <module>
    X=sm.add_constant(X.exog, prepend=False)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exog'
```

Comment: Why do you use `.exog`? AFAICS it should be just `X = sm.add_constant(X, prepend=False)`

Comment: It is, I figured it out, the docs for the logit models say to use .exog and .endog though.